# How can I use dynamic Types in TypeScript React application with React Hook Form

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, react-typescript

I am converting a previous non TypeScript React application to use TypeScript and am having problems with the use of React Hook Form's setValue method.

My component is a reusable container for some data grid filters that are passed in as children. The React Hook Form field values are read and written dynamically from/to a cache and so the component is unaware of the Type of the field values object.

Previously in my non TypeScript version this was not a problem and using the non Generic implementation of useForm allowed me to pass dynamic field names / values to setValue.

However, with TypeScript, setValue is being defined as:

```
(property) setValue: <never>(name: never, value: never, options?: Partial<{
   shouldValidate: boolean;
   shouldDirty: boolean;
   shouldTouch: boolean;
}> | undefined) => void
```

The never type generic means I cannot provide a dynamic value (of type string) as the field name as below:

```
fields.forEach((field, i) => formMethods.setValue(field[0], field[1], { shouldDirty: true }));
```

I am then getting the error **Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'**

I understand that under normal circumstances I would define a Type for the field values object and pass it as a generic to useForm, but how can I instead work with dynamic Types?

Answer (score 0):

So this was fixed by importing the Type UseFormProps from React Hook Form and assigning it to my generic Form Options property, so:

```
interface Props {
    formOptions: UseFormProps,
    ...
};

const FilterContainer = ({
  formOptions,
  ...
} : Props) => {

const formMethods = useForm(formOptions);
```

This then set the definition of setValue to

```
(property) setValue: <string>(name: string, value: any, options?: Partial<{
  shouldValidate: boolean;
  shouldDirty: boolean;
  shouldTouch: boolean;
}> | undefined) => void
```